# Can't export seemingly simple R code to beamer, wrong-type-argument, number-or-marker-p nil

Tags: org-export

I have the following seemingly innocuous org document that I am trying to export to beamer.

```
#+TITLE:     Foo
#+AUTHOR:    foo
#+EMAIL:     foo
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \institute[]{Penn State University} 
#+DATE:      
#+DESCRIPTION: 
#+KEYWORDS: 
#+LANGUAGE:  en
#+BEAMER_THEME: Boadilla
#+BEAMER_HEADER: 
#+latex_class: beamer
#+latex_class_options:
#+latex_header: 
#+latex_header_extra:
#+latex_compiler: pdflatex
#+OPTIONS: H:2 toc:nil
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \AtBeginSection[]{\begin{frame}<beamer>\vfill\centering\usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\vfill\end{frame}}
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \usepackage{pdfpages}
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \makeatletter\beamer@ignorenonframefalse\makeatother
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \usepackage{caption}
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \usepackage{subcaption}
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \usepackage{multicol}
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \definecolor{links}{HTML}{4167E1}
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=,urlcolor=links}
#+STARTUP: beamer
#+OPTIONS: d:(not "RELATED") ^:nil

** Spurious Conclusions

#+begin_src R :exports both :results value :session "*R*" 

  w1 <- c(1, 1, 1) 
  w2 <- c(1, 1, 5) 

  x1 <- w1/sum(w1) 
  print(x1)
  
#+end_src
```

But its not working and I am getting this very odd (to me) cryptic backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p nil)
  jit-lock--run-functions(1166 1232)
  jit-lock-fontify-now(1166 #<marker at 1232 in debug.org<2>>)
  #<subr font-lock-ensure>(1166 #<marker at 1232 in debug.org<2>>)
  polymode-inhibit-during-initialization(#<subr font-lock-ensure> 1166 #<marker at 1232 in debug.org<2>>)
  apply(polymode-inhibit-during-initialization #<subr font-lock-ensure> (1166 #<marker at 1232 in debug.org<2>>))
  font-lock-ensure(1166 #<marker at 1232 in debug.org<2>>)
  org-table-align()
  org-babel-insert-result(((0.333333333333333) (0.333333333333333) (0.333333333333333)) ("value" "replace") ("R" "\nw1 <- c(1, 1, 1) \nw2 <- c(1, 1, 5) \n\nx1 <- w1/sum..." ((:colname-names) (:rowname-names) (:result-params "value" "replace") (:result-type . value) (:results . "value replace") (:exports . "both") (:cache . "no") (:hlines . "no") (:noweb . "no") (:session . "*R*") (:tangle . "no")) "" nil 1008 "(ref:%s)") nil "R" (0 0 257399 34000))
  org-babel-execute-src-block(nil ("R" "\nw1 <- c(1, 1, 1) \nw2 <- c(1, 1, 5) \n\nx1 <- w1/sum..." ((:colname-names) (:rowname-names) (:result-params "replace" "value") (:result-type . value) (:results . "replace value") (:exports . "both") (:tangle . "no") (:session . "*R*") (:noweb . "no") (:hlines . "no") (:cache . "no")) "" nil 1008 "(ref:%s)"))
  org-babel-exp-results(("R" "\nw1 <- c(1, 1, 1) \nw2 <- c(1, 1, 5) \n\nx1 <- w1/sum..." ((:cache . "no") (:colname-names) (:exports . "both") (:hlines . "no") (:noweb . "no") (:result-params "replace" "value") (:result-type . value) (:results . "replace value") (:rowname-names) (:session . "*R*") (:tangle . "no")) "" nil 1008 "(ref:%s)") block nil "a9090b6b64c01c79eab1e3ad8b588c708516fd9e")
  org-babel-exp-do-export(("R" "\nw1 <- c(1, 1, 1) \nw2 <- c(1, 1, 5) \n\nx1 <- w1/sum..." ((:cache . "no") (:colname-names) (:exports . "both") (:hlines . "no") (:noweb . "no") (:result-params "replace" "value") (:result-type . value) (:results . "replace value") (:rowname-names) (:session . "*R*") (:tangle . "no")) "" nil 1008 "(ref:%s)") block "a9090b6b64c01c79eab1e3ad8b588c708516fd9e")
  org-babel-exp-src-block((src-block (:language "R" :switches nil :parameters ":exports both :results value :session \"*R*\"" :begin 1008 :end 1157 :number-lines nil :preserve-indent nil :retain-labels t :use-labels t :label-fmt nil :value "\n  w1 <- c(1, 1, 1) \n  w2 <- c(1, 1, 5) \n\n  x1 <- ..." :post-blank 3 :post-affiliated 1008 :mode planning :granularity element :cached nil :parent (section (:begin 1008 :end 1157 :contents-begin 1008 :contents-end 1154 :robust-begin 1008 :robust-end 1152 :post-blank 3 :post-affiliated 1008 :mode section :granularity element :cached nil :parent (headline (:raw-value "Spurious Conclusions" :begin 983 :end 1235 :pre-blank 1 :contents-begin 1008 :contents-end 1232 :robust-begin 1010 :robust-end 1230 :level 2 :priority nil :tags nil :todo-keyword nil :todo-type nil :post-blank 3 :footnote-section-p nil :archivedp nil :commentedp nil :post-affiliated 983 :title (...) :parent (org-data ...) :cached t :org-element--cache-sync-key (0 . 983))) :org-element--cache-sync-key (0 . 1007))) :org-element--cache-sync-key (0 . 1008))))
  org-babel-exp-process-buffer()
  org-export-as(beamer nil nil nil (:output-file "debug.tex"))
  org-export-to-file(beamer "debug.tex" nil nil nil nil nil org-latex-compile)
  org-beamer-export-to-pdf()
  funcall-interactively(org-beamer-export-to-pdf)
   command-execute(org-beamer-export-to-pdf)
```

Any advice or help debugging this would be most appreciated!

*EDIT*: So a few hours of git bisecting later I found the offending lines in my config. HOWEVER, in my mind this just makes things even more confusing! Help please! What is going on?

If I comment out these lines then everything works perfectly:

```
  ;; (org-babel-do-load-languages
  ;;  'org-babel-load-languages
  ;;  '((R . t)
  ;;    (emacs-lisp . t)
  ;;    (latex . t)))
```

Comment: I was getting `wrong-type-argument` at first, but it refused to stop and give me a backtrace when I did `toggle-debug-on-error` (and I did it a couple of times to make sure that it was enabled). Then I instrumented `org-table-align` with `edebug`: there were three calls, with the third aborting with `wrong-type-argument`. But when I tried to look more closely, the error disappeared and the PDF was produced (correctly AFAICT). Now I cannot make it fail again - weird!

Comment: @NickD It gets werider. See my "EDIT" `(org-babel-do-load-languages ...)` seemed to be the offender... What?!

Comment: *weirder. Not sure what werider means.

Comment: It's how one spells "weirder" when one is werided out...